# spacing checkboxlist label

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkboxlist, spacing

I'm trying to dynamically create a checkboxlist with a quite specific look.
This code adds the checkboxlist correctly, but the spacing is all wrong:

```
foreach (string s in fieldTypes)
{
    dt = sqlDataLayer.getInterpretationField(Guid.Parse(id), s);
    CheckBoxList cbl = new CheckBoxList();
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        string fieldName = dr["fieldName"].ToString();
        string displayName = dr["displayName"].ToString();
        string spacer = "";
        int length = fieldName.Length + displayName.Length;
        length = 50 - length;
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            spacer += "&nbsp;";
        }
        cbl.Items.Add(new ListItem(fieldName+spacer+displayName));
    }
    dvContent.Controls.Add(cbl);
    break;    //This is just because I just wanna test one loop.. I'll remove it later
}
```

**Desired result:**

```
[ ] Test            Test
[ ] LongerTest      Test
[ ] MuchLongerTest  LongerTest
```

**What I'm getting:**

```
[ ] Test           Test
[ ] LongerTest        Test        //These aren't the exact values and lengths,
[ ] MuchLongerTest   LongerTest   //but it's roughly my result.
```

How can I get the spacing right? is there some way of adding a ListItem with two labels? Some other approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two solutions:

1. You can write a control inherits from CheckBoxList and define your layout overriding RenderControl
2. Replace the CheckBoxList with a Gridview/Repeater and use columns, or with manyCheckBoxes anche put them in the desired structure.

Comment: I went with option nr 2. Thanks =)